# Leaflet Map elements sit in DOM but don't render?

Tags: leaflet

Leaflet is *rendering* because I can see all of its elements in the DOM, but nothing else comes to life. All I see is gray.

The only way I can get map tiles to appear is if I delete the position:absolute on the map container, but that creates a bunch of jumbled map tiles. I checked the GIT history to see if  I accidentally changed a style, but no luck.

Here's the code initializing the map:

```
// init everything on page show
$("#map").live('pageshow',function() {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("lat")!=undefined) { var lat = window.localStorage.getItem("lat")} else { var lat = '49.264'; }
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("lng")!=undefined) { var lng = window.localStorage.getItem("lng")} else { var lng = '-123.123'; }
    try {         
        var map = window.map
        map = new L.Map('map-container');
        var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/006282296d334e66a593e55aca6b5ce0/54803/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
        var cloudmadeAttribution = 'Map Data &copy; 2011 OpenStreetMap';
        var cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 18, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution});
        map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, lng), 12).addLayer(cloudmade);
        map.invalidateSize();
    } catch(e) {console.log(e)}
    userMarkers[1] = new L.Marker( new L.LatLng( lat,lng ) , {icon: new iconUser, clickable: true} );
    map.addLayer( userMarkers[1] );
});
```

The environment includes jQuery mobile. Unfortunately, the console does not log any errors and the localStorage above indeed holds valid LatLng values when I inspect it.

A screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Any guesses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how the problem started, but to fix it I went and erased all map container styles and then declared:

```
#map-container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And now the problem is fixed. I've never used such styling before so I cannot speculate on how the problem started.